# Drag&Drop in angular application doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I try to run a drag & drop system on my Angular application, the drag and drop works on an html file with a live-server, but once in my Angular application I can not drag and drop...
If you have an idea... Thanks :)

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<img src="https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/5718897981_10faa45ac3_b-640x624.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="88" height="31">
```

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

And  the dependencies (in case)

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "method-override": "^2.3.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.5",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using JS events (`ondrop`, `ondragover`) whereas you should implement this the angular way using directives. Here's some examples:

[Angular Drag and Drop](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#!/)
[Drag & Drop with HTML5](https://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested)